# Why do we pass a UIViewController to a UINavigationController Class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm abit confused about this controller inside another controller business.  I thought we can just initialze the UInavigationController without initWIthRootViewController.

```
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
controller.title = @"ViewController";
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
```

Sometimes I think i get this, but then when I see something like this it throws me back to nothing.  I've read the doc, but it isn't doing a good job (for me).

Thanks

Comment: what is the question/problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your Navigation controller is managing the display of the items on it's stack.  The rootViewController is the first item for it to display, and first item in the stack. It is a bit different to the other VCs in the stack as AFAIK, it can't be popped.  There are times when the root view controller holds information that is useful to other VCs in the stack.

I guess Apple could have let you push a view controller during setup, but They decided that the concept of a root view controller is a good one, and I can see how it helps the IB/Storyboard implementation.

Comment: What if I have a main view that doesn't uses the navigation controller until a button is tapped, can that main view Also have a root controller?